# How to only capture particular bluetooth button press and let others go to default media player app?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I am making a companion Android app that goes with a car bluetooth device. The bluetooth device in the car has the following buttons: call, end, play/pause, previous, and next.

I wanted to rewire the "next" button to do something in my app. The funny part is that I actually achieved it and it is working perfectly fine, the problem is that app is now getting ALL of the media button presses (i.e. Play, Pause, Previous) instead of going to the default Android music player. I need to figure out how to either (1) only capture the forward button and nothing else or (2) pass the media intent on to the rest of the system. The problem is that I don't know how to do this.

I registered the receiver in my manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And my main activity consists of:

```
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Play button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}          
    else if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pause button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Rewind button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Forward button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
```

Also, it is important that the "next" button only be used in my app, I can't have it forward the next song and run my activity at the same time.